# Bind FileVersion to property in WiX

Tags: wix

As for binding the AssemblyVersion of a specific DLL to WiX File Version, is basically easy:

```
<Product Id="*"
           Name="My Application"
           Language="1033"
           Version="!(bind.FileVersion.MyDll.dll)"
           Manufacturer="My Company"
           UpgradeCode="E7A0C56F-160B-4C67-9AAC-2FF69630EAF9">
```

Is there any way that the same can be achieved with Properties in WiX. Like this:

```
 <Property Id="VERSION">
   <![CDATA[!(bind.FileVersion.MyDll.dll)]]>
 </Property>
```

I need to update an XML file during installation, with the same version number as the one in the specific DLL. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [XmlFile](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/xmlfile.html) Element. It allows you to set values/attributes:

```
<Component Id="webconfig" Guid="PUT-YOUR-GUID-HERE" NeverOverwrite="yes" Win64="yes">
    <File Id="web.config" Source="$(var.bind.ProjectDir)\web.config" KeyPath="yes" />
    <util:XmlFile Id="web.config.VersionInfo" File="[#web.config]" Action="setValue" PreserveModifiedDate="yes" ElementPath="//configuration/appSettings/add[\[]@key='VersionInfo'[\]]" Name="value" Value="[VERSION]" Sequence="1" />
</Component>
```

Comment: Ok. But then I do not get your question?